# String Concatenation

Tags: code-golf, string

**The Challenge**

> Given two strings containing only lowercase letters and no spaces, the result should be the shorter string, followed by an underscore, followed by the longer string with the first instance of a character removed for each character it contains that is in the shorter string.
>
> You can assume the strings will always be different lengths.

**Test Cases:**

```
sale
salinewater
Result: sale_inwater (only the first 'a' in salinewater is removed)

jostling
juggle
Result: juggle_ostin (juggle is the shorter string)

juggle
juggler
Result: juggle_r (a 'g' is removed for every 'g' in the shorter string)
```

**Rules**

> This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: What does smaller string mean? Shorter?

Comment: What does "*remove the first occurrence*" mean when the shorter string has duplicate characters?

Comment: Four days is very short to pick a winner, I'd suggest at least a couple of week at minimum. Also, in the future I'd suggest first posting to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/20260) where challenges can be clarified and improved before going live.

Comment: smaller string is shorter string......sorry for my bad english

Comment: You say input strings will be lowercase. Does that mean they only contain (lowercase) letters? Can input strings contain underscores?

Comment: What should the output for `juggle juggler` be? `juggle_r` (remove for each character instance) or `juggle_gr` (remove for each distinct character)?

Comment: @Pietu1998 That's a good point. We should put this on hold until clarified

Comment: @Pietu1998 it will be juggle_r

Comment: @Ajay please add your clarifications to the challenge itself. Comments aren't meant to be permanent and answerers are not expected to read all comments.

Comment: @Ajay Could you clarify this in the challenge by making an edit? The more relevant information in the question instead of the comments, the more likely votes to re-open will come up. Also, as suggested by _xnor_, it's recommended to first post in the [Sandbox for proposed challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/20260) to retrieve feedback and perfect your challenge before posting it here. Apart from some details this looks like a great first challenge though, so welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Hey MartinEnder and Kevin,                                                                             For sure, I will clarify that in question itself

Comment: @Ajay You don't really need the Todo bit.

Comment: Can we clean up and remove some of these comments now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
++hAlDQ\_.-HG
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2BhAlDQ%5C_.-HG&input=%22jostling%22%2C+%22juggle%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>78</s> <s>75</s> 69 Bytes

```js
const 
     g=(x,y)=>x[y.length]?g(y,x):[...x].map(c=>y=y.replace(c,''))&&x+'_'+y
;

console.log(g.toString().length + 2);   // 69
console.log(g('sale', 'salinewater'))   // sale_inwater
console.log(g('juggle', 'juggler'))     // juggle_r
console.log(g('jostling','juggle'))     // juggle_ostin
```

#### Breakdown

```
x[y.length]?g(y,x):        \\ Make sure that x is the shorter string
[...x]                     \\ Spread string in array of characters
.map(c=>y=y.replace(c,'')) \\ For each character remove its first occurence in y
&&x+'_'+y                  \\ Concat x and changed y
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
x%y|(0<$y)<(0<$x)=y%x|z<-y\\x=x++'_':z
```

*-1 byte thanks to @xnor*

Comment: You can cut a byte by binding `y\\x` for the `0<1` otherwise guard.

Comment: `filter(\`notElem\`x)y` is shorter than `y\\x` with import

Comment: @Damien I think that would remove all occurrences of elements of `x`, not just the first ones.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 262 bytes

```
import java.util.*;String c(String z,String y){int i=0,l=y.length();if(z.length()>l)return c(y,z);List x=new ArrayList();for(;i<l;x.add(y.toCharArray()[i++]));for(Object q:z.toCharArray())x.remove(q);String r="";for(i=0;i<x.size();r+=x.get(i++));return z+"_"+r;}
```

Can probably be golfed some more by just using arrays without the lists..

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/bB5brb)

```
import java.util.*;
class M{
  static String c(String z, String y){
    int i = 0,
        l = y.length();
    if(z.length() > l){
      return c(y, z);
    }
    List x = new ArrayList();
    for(; i < l; x.add(y.toCharArray()[i++]));
    for(Object q : z.toCharArray()){
      x.remove(q);
    }
    String r = "";
    for(i = 0; i < (x.size()); r += x.get(i++));
    return z+"_"+r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("sale", "salinewater"));
    System.out.println(c("jostling", "juggle"));
    System.out.println(c("juggle", "juggler"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
sale_inwater
juggle_ostin
juggle_r
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 156 Bytes

```
String a(String x,String y){int l=x.length(),m=y.length();String b=l>m?x:y,s=m<l?y:x;for(char c:s.toCharArray()){b=b.replaceFirst(""+c,"");}return s+"_"+b;}
```

This can probably be golfed some more.

**Ungolfed & test cases**

```
interface A {
    static String a(String x,String y){
        int l=x.length(),m=y.length();
        String b=l>m?x:y,s=m<l?y:x;
        for(char c:s.toCharArray()){
            b=b.replaceFirst(""+c,"");
        }
        return s+"_"+b;
    }
    
    static void main(String[]a) {
        System.out.println(a("sale","salinewater"));
        System.out.println(a("jostling","juggle"));
        System.out.println(a("juggle","juggler"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 65 bytes

```
->a,b{a,b=b,a if a.size>b.size;a.chars.map{|e|b.sub!e,""};a+?_+b}
```

#### ungolfed

```
->a, b{
  a, b = b, a if a.size > b.size
  a.chars.map { |e|
    b.sub! e, ""
  }
  a + ?_ + b
}
```

#### 61 bytes(in case the argument is an array of strings)

```
->a{a.sort_by!(&:size);a[0].chars.map{|c|a[1].sub!c,""};a*?_‌​}
```

Thank you, [m-chrzan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58569/m-chrzan)!

Comment: `gsub!` doesn't work here - you're supposed to remove the first occurance of each letter. Fortunately, `sub!`, which does exactly that, is a byte shorter.

Comment: Also, I think you need to name the lambda in this case, since you do end up calling it. However, doing `a,b=b,a if a.size>b.size` to exchange the strings is non-recursive, and saves you another byte.

Comment: @m-chrzan Oh, I didn't observe carefully the question. Thanks!

Comment: 61 bytes, input as an array of strings: `->a{a.sort_by!(&:size);a[0].chars.map{|c|a[1].sub!c,""};a*?_}`

Comment: @m-chrzan Great! I added your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>81</s> 72 bytes

```python
a,b=sorted(input(),key=len)
for c in a:b=b.replace(c,"",1)
print a+"_"+b
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/Dfgs/1)

Comment: I think you can save 9 bytes by replacing the first two lines with `a,b=sorted(input(),key=len)`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 154 Bytes

```
list($f,$s)=strlen($b=$argv[2])<strlen($a=$argv[1])?[$b,$a]:[$a,$b];foreach(str_split($f)as$x)$s=preg_replace("#(.*?)".$x."(.*)#","$1$2",$s);echo$f."_$s";
```

Instead of `$s=preg_replace("#(.*?)".$x."(.*)#","$1$2",$s);` you can also use `if($z=strstr($s,$x))$s=strstr($s,$x,1).substr($z,1);`

Answer (score 0):

### R, 161 bytes

This turned out to be much longer than I expected, albeit, string manipulation is usually tedious in R. I feel that this should easily be golfable by just using another approach.

```
function(x,y){s=strsplit;if(nchar(x)>nchar(y)){v=y;w=x}else{v=x;w=y};v=s(v,"")[[1]];w=s(w,"")[[1]];j=0;for(i in v){j=j+1;if(i==w[j])w[j]=""};cat(v,"_",w,sep="")}
```

#### Ungofled

```
function(x,y){
    s=strsplit                      # alias for stringsplit
    if(nchar(x)>nchar(y)){v=y;w=x}  # assign v/w for the short/long strings
    else{v=x;w=y}
    v=s(v,"")[[1]]                  # split short string into vector
    w=s(w,"")[[1]]                  # split long string into vector
    j=0
    for(i in v){                    # for each char in short string, check
        j=j+1                       # if is equal to corresponding char in
        if(i==w[j])w[j]=""          # long, replace long with "" if true
    }
    cat(v,"_",w,sep="")             # insert _ and print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 78 bytes

```
def f(a:String,b:String):String={if(a.size>b.size)f(b,a)else
a+"_"+(b diff a)}
```

Explanation:

```
def f(a:String,b:String):String={ //define a method f which has two String parameters and returns a String
                                  //(because it's recursive, scala can't figure out the return type)
  if (a.size > b.size)            //make sure that a is the shorter string
    f(b, a)
  else
    a+"_"+(b diff a)              //`b diff a` removes all elements/chars of a from b
}
```